# Input controls for keypad (Milkman Conspiracy)

Tags: macos, psychonauts

I'm replaying this awesome game (played it on Xbox way back then).

I'm stuck at the milkman conspiracy part as I can't input the digits on the keypad to access the post office. I can move the cursor but not press anything but <kbd>x</kbd> to exit. I assume that <kbd>f</kbd> is the key to press but much to my surprise it did nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I played that level a week ago, on the Mac version of Psychonauts. As I remember it, I could use the arrow keys to highlight a number button with a green border, and <kbd>Space</kbd> (the “Jump” control) to press the highlighted button. After I inputted four numbers, the keypad screen automatically closed.

Comment: For a three-sentence answer, I don't think a tl;dr is necessary.